# Brown residue in coolant reservoir

Tags: engine, coolant-reservoir

Truck temp gauge went to hot. Coolant reservoir was full. Truck then sat for 9 hours. Checked oil...2 quarts low. My coolant reservoir was now brown and gross as well as radiator cap. What has happened?

Comment: How many miles on vehicle?